# Asking for the sake of learning or debugging my own solution to already-solved-problem

Tags: discussion, questions

Many times I ask questions after I failed to come up with my own solution.

So, how nice is it to ask a follow-up question for knowing what is wrong with my code not for solving the **already-solved-problem** in order to learn more about why my code is bugged or not working?

Comment: I think it is much better to ask an additional question if the other issue is solved already instead of changing the question (but adding additional content)

Comment: In my opinion these are perfectly valid questions. I would include your original motivation in the question to be sure you don't get answers with workarounds but with explanations.